# A solvable quintic with the root $x=(\sqrt[5]{p}+\sqrt[5]{q})^5$ - what are the other roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I derived a two parameter quintic equation with the root:

> $$x=(\sqrt[5]{p}+\sqrt[5]{q})^5,~~~~~p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$$

$$\color{blue}{x^5}-5(p+q)\color{blue}{x^4}+5(2p^2-121pq+2q^2)\color{blue}{x^3}-5(2p^3+381p^2q+381pq^2+2q^3)\color{blue}{x^2}+\\ + 5(p^4-121p^3q+381p^2q^2-121pq^3+q^4)\color{blue}{x}-(p+q)^5=0 \tag{1}$$

> I'm unsure what the other roots are.

My thoughts: this is really a $25$ degree equation, it has $25$ roots.

Since there are 5 fifth degree roots, it makes sence, that we have:

$$x=y^5$$

$$y_{kn}=w_{5k}\sqrt[5]{p}+w_{5n}\sqrt[5]{q},~~~~~k,n=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$

With $w_{5k}$ - $5$th roots of unity and $\sqrt[5]{p},\sqrt[5]{q}$ - principal roots.

> Is this correct?
>
> If we have $25$ different roots of the $25$th degree equation, what about the quintic equation $(1)$?

---

**Edit**

Another possible way - we can probably write:

$$x=p(1+\sqrt[5]{q/p})^5=q(1+\sqrt[5]{p/q})^5$$

Then we have $5$ possible roots inside the bracket.

Is this the correct way to get all the roots of $(1)$?

Comment: That's not a $25$th degree polynomial in $x$ just a 5th degree.  I'm not following your logic that leads you to write $x=y^5$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I never said it was a $25$th degree polynomial in $x$, I said it was a $25$th degree polynomial in $y$ - a new variable I introduced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x = p(1 + (\frac qp)^{\frac 15})^5 \in \Bbb Q((\frac qp)^{\frac 15})$.

And so the splitting field of your degree $5$ polynomial is $\Bbb Q((\frac qp)^{\frac 15},\zeta_5)$, the conjugates of $x$ are obtained by multiplying $(\frac qp)^{\frac 15}$ with a power of $\zeta_5$.

Also this is not really a degree $25$ equation.

If you naïvely look at the "conjugate" $(\zeta_5 p^\frac15 + \zeta_5 q^\frac 15)^5$, well it turns out you can factor out $\zeta_5$ and this is equal to your original $x$. So $x$ doesn't have as many distinct conjugates as you would think it should have.

Comment: It doesn't matter which parameter we bring outside the bracket?

Comment: no it doesn't. If $p^\frac 15$ is any root of $p$ and $q^\frac 15$ is any root of $q$ then after factoring by $p^\frac 15$ you factor a total of $p$, and $(q^\frac 15)/(p^\frac 15)$ is a root of $q/p$ that I wrote $(q/p)^\frac 15$

Comment: @mercio: I gave a similar answer but connected it to the DeMoivre quintic.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are getting at. Since there are actually five solutions $\alpha$ to the equation,

$$\alpha^5 = p$$

then it makes sense that $p^{1/5}+q^{1/5} = z$ should be the root of a $25$th deg eqn, correct? This is essentially given by your equation slightly modified as,

> **Eq.1:**
>   $$z^{25}-5(p+q)z^{20}+5(2p^2-121pq+2q^2)z^{15}-5(2p^3+381p^2q+381pq^2+2q^3)z^{10}+\\ + 5(p^4-121p^3q+381p^2q^2-121pq^3+q^4)z^5-(p+q)^5=0 $$

However, since you *raised* your sum to a fifth power $x = \big(p^{1/5}+q^{1/5}\big)^5 = z^5$, *you lost $20$ of the roots*,

> **Eq.2:**
>   $$x^{5}-5(p+q)x^{4}+5(2p^2-121pq+2q^2)x^{3}-5(2p^3+381p^2q+381pq^2+2q^3)x^{2}+\\ + 5(p^4-121p^3q+381p^2q^2-121pq^3+q^4)x-(p+q)^5=0 $$

But there is another way to get a quintic out of $(1)$: *one can factor it*. This can be done by using appropriately chosen $p,q$, namely,

$$p=\tfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}, \quad q=\tfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}$$

and $(1)$ simplifies as,
$$z^{25} + 5 b z^{20} + 5 (125 + 2 b^2) z^{15} + 5 b (-375 + 2 b^2) z^{10} + 5 (625 + 125 b^2 + b^4) z^5 + b^5 = 0$$
This factors into a $5$-deg and $20$-deg $P(z)$, [easily done by Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5Bz%5E%7B25%7D%20%2B%205%20b%20z%5E%7B20%7D%20%2B%205%20(125%20%2B%202%20b%5E2)%20z%5E%7B15%7D%20%2B%205%20b%20(-375%20%2B%202%20b%5E2)%20z%5E%7B10%7D%20%2B%205%20(625%20%2B%20125%20b%5E2%20%2B%20b%5E4)%20z%5E5%20%2B%20b%5E5%5D) or *Mathematica*,

$$(z^5+5z^3+5z+b)\, P(z) = 0$$

with the $5$-deg as the familiar ***DeMoivre quintic***. Thus, the $25$ possible sums of,

$$z = p^{1/5}+q^{1/5} = \Big(\tfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}\Big)^{1/5} +\Big(\tfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}\Big)^{1/5}$$

solve the DeMoivre quintic, as well as a $20$th deg eqn you can see by clicking on the WA link above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This is a very important point